# Using directives without the injector

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular 1.x, is it possible to write a directive and use it **without** registering it with the injector?

My use case is attempting to avoid registering components in a central location that might be clobbered by different teams working concurrently on the same application.

Angular 2 will solve my problem with hierarchical injectors, but it is not production ready.

Alternatively, can I instantiate more than one injector to be used in a sandboxed manner?